# Html- I cant stick my pictures to a fixed point on the page

Tags: html, css, fixed

So I created my divs within my css and have linked them to my index file.
So the problem is whenever i zoom out of my page (using the scroll wheel) the images move to the left but the background stays within the middle of the page. I was wondering how to make an image have a fixed position on the page whilst not effecting it when i zoom out of the page.

This is a piece of code which dosen't have an effect on an image (problem with  this piece of code is that i want some pictures to be placed within a certain position (by using pixels)):

```
#top-left
{
    width:200px;
    height:200px;
    border-right: thick hotpink solid;
    border-bottom: thick hotpink solid;
}
```

This is a piece of code which does have an effect on an image:

```
#top-left2
{
    width:200px;
    height:200px;
    position:absolute; 
    left:464px;
    top: 354px;
    border-right: thick hotpink solid;
    border-bottom: thick hotpink solid;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want the background image to not scroll and be fixed try this:

```
html { 
  background: url(images/bg.jpg) no-repeat center center fixed; 
  -webkit-background-size: cover;
  -moz-background-size: cover;
  -o-background-size: cover;
  background-size: cover;
}
```

You can refer to it here: https://css-tricks.com/perfect-full-page-background-image/

Otherwise, if you want to do this with any div you can apply fixed positioning:

```
#top-left2
{
    width:400px;
    height:200px;
    position:fixed; 
    z-index: 500;
    left:464px;
    top: 0;
    border-right: thick hotpink solid;
    border-bottom: thick hotpink solid;
    background-color: yellow;
}
```